# In the Pokémon anime who is this?

Tags: pokemon

I watched this video from an episode from the original series

And I saw a girl with Sabrina:

[image: sabrina with girl]

Who was is it? I looked on Bulbapedia but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: I'm...confused.  If you had watched the episode, you'd know who this particular character is since it's explained either in this or the immediately following episode.

Comment: To close-voters: this question is undoubtedly terrible, but it's not the kind of identification request that's off-topic because it gives us the source series.

Comment: Please add which episode this comes from.

Answer (score 6):

That is Sabrina's doll. The Sabrina episodes are kind of creepy, because Sabrina's mind has apparently been split in half. Her cold, calculating, sinister side lives in her body, while the playful little girl she never was lives in the doll.

Answer (score 2):

Sabrina, a psychic type gym leader, has telikinetic and psychic abilities.This doll is, in essence, possessed by Sabrina's childish half.